# How can I vertically center a value in a PivotTable cell with Aspose Cells?

Tags: pivot-table, centering, aspose-cells

I know how to vertically center cell values when they can be defined by their row location, namely get a reference to them, create a style, assign values to the style, and then assign the style to the cell, like so:

```
cell = pivotTableSheet.Cells[4, 0];
cell.PutValue(AnnualContractProductsLabel);
style = cell.GetStyle();
style.HorizontalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Center;
style.VerticalAlignment = TextAlignmentType.Center;
style.Font.IsBold = true;
pivotTableSheet.Cells.SetRowHeight(4, 25);
style.BackgroundColor = CONTRACT_ITEM_COLOR;
pivotTableSheet.Cells[4, 0].SetStyle(style);
```

But what about for recurring values, such as those that are generated for a PivotTable?

I create a row value like so:

```
pivotTable.AddFieldToArea(Aspose.Cells.Pivot.PivotFieldType.Row, DESCRIPTION_COLUMN);
pivotTable.RowHeaderCaption = "Description";
```

...which appears like this (the values beneath "Description" such as "Anise, *" and "Artichokes, *", "Asparagus, *" etc.):

[image]

I want those values vertically centered, rather than at the top. How can I manage that?

Comment: What I understand is that you wish to merge the cells and then vertically align the contents to center. For instance, you probably wish to bring the value ANISE, FENNEL 12 CT to the center of cells X9:X12 (where X is the column name). If my understanding is correct, I am afraid this cannot be accomplished with Aspose.Cells or Excel application. Reason being, Excel does not allow to merge ranges within a Pivot Table. You can confirm this on your side as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do any formatting with the pivot table cell, then please create a Style object and then call this method. It should fix your issue.

```
mPivotTable.Format((2, 4, style);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: What do the first two arguments (2 and 4) signify/control?